# Call product search from custom hook

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, search

I am trying to make search request from my custom form. For this I have an AJAX call on form submit:

```
jQuery("#header-search").on('submit', function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: jQuery(this).serialize()
        })
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res)
        })
        return false
    })
```

In my functions.php I have:

```
function custom_search () {
    //WHAT SHOULD I CALL HERE
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_search', 'custom_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_custom_search', 'custom_search' );
```

I am not sure if this should be made as AJAX but I don't really understand what action should I put on the search form in the HTML. Everything seems like a mess for me. Can you assist me this? Appreciating every suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that no AJAX is needed. If somebody don't understand all the fancy example around, you just need to use the `pre_get_posts` hook. In my case what I did is:

```
function custom_product_search($query) {
    $query->query_vars['post_parent'] = htmlentities($_GET['model']) ?? htmlentities($_GET['make']);
    return $query;
}
add_action("pre_get_posts", 'custom_product_search');
```

I don't know if this is the correct solution but it is working one.